# How to use jQuery to get Input Field Value of dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm currently using **Meteor/Blaze framework** to build a table. The row in the table will change according to the selected supplier. I have added `class={{_id}}` to the field and `q.{{_id}}` , `lot.{{_id}}` , and `exp.{{_id}}` to the quantity, lot , and expire date **INPUT**.

I'm trying to write a Submit Events to get these value and pass it to the **Mongo** Database. Please suggest a good way to loop through these rows to get the value.

**Website Image**

[image]

**Part of the code**

receiveForm template

```
<template name="receiveForm">
...
<select data-placeholder="Select an option" class="sel2js form-control select select-primary" id="supplier_sel" name="supplier">
      {{#each suppliers}}
        {{> sel_supplier}}
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- Receive Lot Table -->
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Current Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit of Measurement</th>
        <th>Receive Quantity</th>
        <th>Lot No</th>
        <th>Exp Date (DD/MM/YYYY)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each items}}
        {{> receiveRow2}}
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary btn-wide" id="submitNewReceive" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-embossed btn-warning btn-wide" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</div>
</form>
```

receiveRow2 template

```
<template name="receiveRow2">
  <tr id="{{_id}}">
    <td class="pn">{{name}}</td>
    <td class="pq">{{totalQuantity}}</td>
    <td>{{uomid.name}} ({{uomid.unit}} {{uomid.unitname}}/{{uomid.name}})</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="q.{{_id}}" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lot.{{_id}}" placeholder="Lot No XX/YYYY" /></td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group datetimepicker text-primary">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        <input class="set-due-date form-control" name="exp.{{_id}}" type="text" placeholder="วัน/เดือน/ปี"/>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.receiveForm.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template){
    var supplierSelected = Template.instance().supplierSelected;
    items = Products.find({suppliers: supplierSelected.get()});
    event.preventDefault();
    docdate = event.target.docdate.value;
    supplier = event.target.supplier_sel.value;
    console.log("---event---");
    console.log(docdate)
    console.log(supplier)
    items.forEach(function(item){
      ????
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 4 its missing a var before items, and also in line 6, 7.

After that I think you can loop on them.(But they will come from the DB).

BUT if you want to get the input values, why would you ask for a data in MongoDB?
Also I would prefer to get DB values as a promise.

```
var items = Promise.resolve(Products.find({suppliers: supplierSelected.get()});
```

and get back the items in this way:

```
items.then(function(item){console.log(item)})
```

Comment: I was trying to get the ID from the DB so I can try to find a way to get the input name=q.ID, lot.ID value.

Comment: And you want to fill the values with the DB stored values?

Comment: Now I'm trying to find a way get the  input field values so I can  fill it in DB.

Comment: I think, You can get it if you catch the tbody all tr element.
If you loop trought on that elements, you can gett all the information, what needs for the DB update
If you ident all input field in each line for example with extra class, 
receive-quanty, lot-no, exp-date than:
`var trs = $("tboody tr"); // get all trs`
`for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){`
  `var trID = foo //get all trs ID`
  `var input1Val = bar //get the input fields value`
 ` var input2Val = foobar `
  `meteor.update(id, input1, input2 input3)`
`}`
And you can update your meteor collections line by line